# How can i deny the event to be fired on a special item

Tags: jquery

I have a div with some inputs. now i would like to fire the event every time there is a change on my inputs. so far everything is fine :) but i don't want the event to befired if i select a file with my first input.

[see my Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5s6yL/1/)

here is the source

HTML:

```
<div class="someForm">
<input type="file" name="logo" class="logoselector" />
<br />
<div class="row-fluid">
    <input type="text" name="firmenname" />
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="adresse" />
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="telefon" />
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="fax" />
</div>
</div>
```

here is the jquery

```
$('.someForm').on('change', function(){
        alert('changed');
});
```

i already tried some constructs with :not(...) but no results :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using [**:not()**](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [**:first**](http://api.jquery.com/first/)

```
$('.someForm input:not(:first)').on('change', function(){
        alert('changed');
});
```

This way jQuery will look for all inputs but not the first: `:not(:first)`

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5s6yL/3/)

---

You could also target the type `file`, by using [**:file**](http://api.jquery.com/file-selector/) inside the [**:not()**](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

Like:

```
$('.someForm input:not(:file)').on('change', function() {
    alert('changed');
});
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5s6yL/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Add `:not` and `:first`

```
$('.someForm input:not(":first")').on('change', function(){
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5s6yL/2/)**

Comment: it is good but in my case its better if the element isn't fix :) so :not(:file) is good for me

Comment: What do you mean by "isn't fix"?

Comment: @j08691: Not the OP, but I'm assuming he means not fixed in position. As in, it could move about the page and not just be the first element.

Comment: Yes, @ColinDeClue was right :) it could happen that the item isn't the first one so input:not(:file) is perfect :D i had some like input:not(.className) but that didn't worked :D

Answer (score 1):

You can add a selector as the second argument in `.on()` to exclude inputs of `type='file'`:

```
$('.someForm').on('change', ':input[type!="file"]', function() {
    alert('changed');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your selector like this:

```
$('.someForm :not(:file)').on('change', function() {
    alert('changed');
});
```

**[Demon](http://jsfiddle.net/rwY3k/)**

Comment: Did you try the "demon" ? :-) It's working on Chrome, FF and Safari on my end.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `e.target.className`:

```
$('.someForm').on('change', function(e){
    if (e.target.className != 'logoselector') {
        alert('changed');
    }
});
```